# Как с помощью Selenium на Java найти именно строчку HTML кода

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Например есть страница и мне нужно проверить присутствует ли в HTML коде такая строчка кода
`<script src="//yastatic.net/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы проверить существование `<script>` сразу с нужным атрибутом, воспользуемся `By.xpath`:

```
driver.isElementPresent(By.xpath("//script[src()='\/\/yastatic.net/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js']"))
```